# Ruby on Rails deployment on Heroku - bootstrap-sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I have quite problem with deploying on heroku. Really don't no why it doesn't work.

**Here is my gem file:**

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.0'
gem 'pg'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
end
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.8.1", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 1.7.0", :group => :test
gem "email_spec", ">= 1.2.1", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.3.0", :group => :test
gem "capybara", ">= 1.1.2", :group => :test
gem "database_cleaner", ">= 0.7.1", :group => :test
gem "launchy", ">= 2.0.5", :group => :test
gem "devise", ">= 2.0.4"
gem 'haml-rails', '>= 0.3.4', :group => :development
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.2'
```

**Heroku log:**

```
 cache: [GET /] miss 
 /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'         
 vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

**Simple app layout**

```
%html
  %head
  %title iPinTeam
  %meta{:charset => "utf-8"}
  %meta{"http-equiv" => "X-UA-Compatible", :content => "IE=edge,chrome=1"}
  %meta{:name => "viewport", :content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"}
  %meta{:content => "", :name => "description"}
  %meta{:content => "", :name => "author"}
  = stylesheet_link_tag :application, :media => "all"
  = javascript_include_tag :application
  = csrf_meta_tags
%body{:class => params[:controller]}
 .navbar.navbar-fixed-top
  .navbar-inner
    .container
    = render 'shared/navigation'
#container.container
  #main{:role => "main"}
    - flash.each do |name, msg|
      = content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) 
    = yield
%footer
```

Sorry if is the question totally stupid, I'm little bit confused about why it is given this error:( In logs are also many errors in:

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.0
vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.0
etc...
```

On the heroku is still poor - We're sorry, but something went wrong.

Think that the problem is maybe with gem bootstrap-sass on heroku. I already tried switch to thin web server but it was total mess:( Can someone help me with this and maybe little bit describe the error. If some additional information will be needed, gonna post them immediately.Thank you...

Comment: Have u precompiled your assets,if not precompiled and then deployed. Might be more log info is useful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will need to precompile your assets before uplading to heroku.

Try `rake assets:precompile` and then upload to Heroku.

Answer (score 6):

I could not view the site with bootstrap CSS on Heroku so I did the following change on `config/environments/production.rb`, change the line:

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

To:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Answer (score 3):

On the same theme of asset compilation as other answers, Heroku also [requires](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) the following line in your **config/application.rb**:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

I believe if you do this, you shouldn't have to run `rake assets:precompile` before deploying on the Cedar stack (at least I haven't needed to).

**Update**

I will add for reference here that because I've also used gems that require me to set `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = true` in **application.rb**, so I usually had to precompile my assets before doing a manual deployment to Heroku. However, after running
`$ heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a HEROKU_APP_NAME` ([reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile)),
I didn't need to run `rake assets:precompile` anymore and Heroku compiled my assets for me. I just hope Heroku keep this functionality going forward.

Answer (score 3):

- rake assets:precompiled
- config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  .....
  all those methods doesn't work for me.

this work for me:
go to **config**/***environment***/***production.rb***

change:   config.assets.compile = false

to:       config.assets.compile = true

Answer (score 2):

Use [bootstrap-sass-rails](https://github.com/yabawock/bootstrap-sass-rails) instead...

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
https://www.bootstrapcdn.com
```

I just include that links and this work fine for me.
For me that was good solution.

Also I use :
 1. rake assets:precompile; 
 2. config.assets.compile = true